# Delete YouTube shortcut in Dash

Tags: 18.04, gnome-dash

A "YouTube" shortcut mysteriously appeared in the Dash Application Launcher (the 9 dots icon). It appeared a couple of reboots after I updated Ubuntu. It seems to be just a link to the youtube website. I don't have any auto updating on, and I have hardly any apps installed. See screenshot.

I can't figure out how to get rid of it. I've tried...

On the icon in the Dash: right-mouse-click > Show Details -> I get: "no application found".

Launch the 'Ubuntu Software' app > 'Installed' tab -> its not there.

`sudo find / -iname "youtube*"` -> no result

I've tried looking in these folders...

```
/usr/share/applications/  
~/.local/share/applications/    
/usr/local/share/applications/    
/usr/share/applications/  
/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/  
/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/applications/
```

[image: Launcher screenshot]

Comment: Hello. By launcher usually it is meant the list on the right had side. Default location. That is not what you are showing. What you show appears to be the Software Center.

Comment: It might be in a .desktop file that doesn't contain "youtube" in the filename?

Comment: Thanks @David. Although I though the Software Center was the icon of an orange bag with 'A' on it - now called 'Ubuntu Software'. For the app launcher I've shown in the screen-shot, I've seen some call this 'Dash Home'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the offending desktop file this way:

```
find / -name '*.desktop' ! -path '/run/user*' -exec grep -H "Name=YouTube" {} \; 2>/dev/null
```

From the location of the file and the contents, you will likely be able to see where it might have come from.

Comment: Thanks, I deleted this:
~/.gnome/apps/chrome-agimnkijcaahngcdmfeangaknmldooml-Default.desktop
and this:
~/.local/share/applications/chrome-agimnkijcaahngcdmfeangaknmldooml-Default.desktop